# What's a blow-up diagram of 3D parts called?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

E.g. Where you've got a photo of the main part (I.e. a circuit board) in the middle, and images of other parts coming off from it, down to the screws and nuts.

What's the name of this diagram?

Comment: I think you almost have it: maybe [exploded view diagram](https://www.google.com/search?q=exploded+diagram&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=Sr-PWOOcEI2w8wfh9aegCQ)?

Comment: Interesting that _blow up_ means _explode_, isn't it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

An **exploded-view drawing** is a diagram, picture, schematic or technical drawing of an object, that shows the relationship or order of assembly of various parts. It shows the components of an object slightly separated by distance, or suspended in surrounding space in the case of a three-dimensional exploded diagram.

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploded-view_drawing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exploded-view_drawing)

Comment: For comparison, also see *illistrated parts breakdown (IPB)*. An example - https://books.google.com/books?id=0dUXAAAAYAAJ&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false